# Receiving error TF277003 when trying to update TFS 2010 project to 2012

Tags: tfs

When trying to update a TFS 2010 project to 2012, I'm receiving the following error:

TF277003: Cannot add more than one upgrade process template from team project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  The search here and google both brought up nothing...

Comment: is there anything special about yoru upgrade process template at all? do you know if you're currently using it for any builds?

Comment: Hi Betty, Nothing special that I know of.  I just used the TFS upgrade wizar and it keeps failing out at the same place.  I'd post my log here, but the character count is killing me... It was being used for builds.  I've removed all build controllers and agents, and i'm receiving the same error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Here's my log [link](http://justpaste.it/1hrd)

Comment: Try using the api to set the current upgrade template as custom using the api - this blog post may help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/04/08/tfs-2010-managing-build-process-templates-what-are-those.aspx